# Is this sql input validation secure?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I'm currently developing a database class for a project I've been working on.  I would like to know if the following function has any holes or errors in it that would allow for someone to use MySQL injection.

```
public function sql_validate($var)
{
    if (is_null($var))
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else if (is_string($var))
    {
        return "'" . $this->sql_escape($var) . "'";
    }
    else if (is_bool($var))
    {
        return intval($var);
    }
    else
    {
        return $var;
    }
}
```

Here's the function sql_escape which is called for strings.

```
private function sql_escape($string)
{
    if (!$this->db_connection)
    {
        return @mysql_real_escape_string($string);
    }

    return @mysql_real_escape_string($string, $this->db_connection);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string` uses whatever escaping mode is best, therefore it is fairly secure.

However, may I suggest an alternative. Why create a database class when there are several out there which utilize a much more secure method - Prepared statements. In a nutshell these work by separating SQL logic from user inputted data.

I would suggest using the [PDO CLASS](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php).

Also, you should really avoid using error suppression `@` in PHP. As this tends to suppress errors which you might not even expect.

The following article is a fairly straightforward [introduction to PDO.](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)